# Integrate authentication to existing Laravel project and users database

Tags: php, laravel

I am a totally newbie to Laravel, but after following lots and lots of guide, my project was really going well.

Now, I have a user table named `UsersTable`, which is going to store both `Username` and `Password`.

However, after trying `php artisan make:auth` and a lot of Googling, I found no clear, exact way of defining both the User table name, and the Username-Password field used for authentication.

I've tried the original Email-Password authentication on the table named `users` on another project I created for trying this, and it works like a charm. I believe that as Laravel already provide the authentication system, why reinvent the wheels when (I believe) there's a way to customise it.

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `php artisan make:auth` and then :

To change the default table from users which uses the User model
you have to navigate to : `config/auth.php`

And make these changes

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\UsersTable::class, //put the right model name here or you can use database driver
        ],
    ],
```

To change the table for an eloquent model you can do this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class UsersTable extends Model
    {
        /**
         * The table associated with the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'UsersTable';
    }
```

To change the default login credential from email to user name , just add this to the **Authcontroller** generated by laravel

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected $username = 'username';  // you can put whatever column you want here from your table
```

**Now**
edit laravel generated Views and change the email input name to `name="username"` then extend the `main.blade.php`, do some styling and you are good to go i guess

**EDIT :** Dont forget to change the validation stuff

Comment: Thank you! What about the Password field? Can I do $password = 'PassWordField'?

Comment: hmm i dont realy know about that but give it a shot and btw if this worked for you, please declare this question as answered by ticking the green mark under the voting section

Answer (score 0):

Laravel basic authentication system is not the fastest way to create your own auth method ... I suggest to you [Sentinel Package](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0) to customize your authentications ...

for example to authenticate your user by using user name you can do like this :

```
Sentinel::authenticate(array(
    'username'    => 'john.doe',
    'password' => 'foobar',
));
```

for me it's the fastest way to customize your authentication method i hope that will help you.